# Reload video onclick and add image to video when play & pause just like youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

When I click the video icon to show the video, the video will display block and auto-play, and the user can click the video screen to play and pause.

The problems I'm facing now are:

1. The video started to load if I add auto-play to the video even I didn't click to show it.
2. After I click play/pause the video and click the video icon to show it again, the video will start from the time it play/pause, but i wanted it to reload again, which mean every time the user click to show the video, it will start from 0.
3. When the user click pause, the video will appear a pause image, just like the youtube.

Here is the fiddle, I'm not sure why the video icon not working at the fiddle, But it works well in my web.

https://jsfiddle.net/7uxvc1p0/3/

Here is my script,

```
function showVideo(id) {    
    $('#divVideo' + id).fadeIn();
    $('#divVideo' + id).addClass('selectedVideo');
    $('#' + id).addClass('selectedVideoTitle');
    video.load();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.autoplay = true;
};

function clsBtn() {
    $('.videowrapper').fadeOut();
    $(".selectedVideo").removeClass('selectedVideo');
    $('.selectedVideoTitle').removeClass('selectedVideoTitle');
};

$("video").click(function(e){
    // get click position 
    var clickY = (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
    var height = parseFloat( $(this).height() );

    // avoids interference with controls
    if(clickY > 0.82*height) return;
    // toggles play / pause
    this.paused ? this.play(function(){
        $(".videopause").removeClass("videopausedisplay");
    }) : this.pause(function(){
        $(".videopause").addClass("videopausedisplay");
    });
});
```